# Find div beginning with a class in Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am using Isolated styles for my React Components. Like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import style from './book.css';

const Book = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        <div className={style.book_container}>
            <div className={style.book}>{name}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Book;
```

Now I want to write unit test for this component. I want to check if the `Book` component has been rendered correctly. I am doing that by checking if the rendered markup has the class `book_container` in it. But the problem is that because the rendered class name actually has a unique hash appended to it like `book_container_Uqwe33232`. So how can I do this, given that the hash code is dynamically generated at run time?

I tried:

```
expect(shallow(<Book name='Harry Potter' />).find(`div[class^='book_container']`).exists()).toBe(true)
```

But it did not work. I am running Enzyme version 3.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Since the vote summary showed votes from 2020, I assume that I'm not the only one getting trouble with it recently, so I'm sharing a work around with anyone, because no proper solution seems to exist.

I'm using Material-UI which generates the same kind of dynamic classes. The same CSS selector works in the Console, with Vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="makeStyles-listItem"]');
```

and in jQuery project too. `^` for begin with, `$` end with, `*` contains. But with Enzyme, it could not work. My class has multiple names and `makeStyles-listItem-168` was in the middle. I'm not gonna pretend I understand why it doesn't work, but since the test is manipulating the DOM explicitly, then I used my old techniques, adding custom attribute, with `data-[attribute_name]` (`data-` to comply with w3c html standard):

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import style from './book.css';

const Book = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        <div className={style.book_container} data-type="book-container">
            <div className={style.book}>{name}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Book;
```

And then you can easily select by your custom attribute:

```
expect(shallow(<Book name='Harry Potter' />).find(`div[data-type='book-container']`).exists()).toBe(true)
```

You can combine it with substring selectors chars like the 3 `^ $ *`.

Answer (score -5):

It looks like from the [Enzyme docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) that the way to test the existence of a subelement inside a shallow wrapper is to call `to.have.length(1)`

An example from the same page:

```
 it('should render an `.icon-star`', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.icon-star')).to.have.length(1);
 });
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. Please read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: The query you are making to find the subelement is correct - `(`div[class^='book_container']`)` will find any element beginning with `book_container`. What error are you getting?

Comment: The test simply fails by saying that 'expected true but got false`.

Comment: Why don't you try changing the matcher like I suggested and see if anything changes? You can also define the wrapper on a separate line and call wrapper.debug() to output the wrapper to the console.